# Socket already in use, but is not listed (mpd)?

Tags: socket, mpd

Running

```
$ mpd
```

I am prompted with

> socket: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use

But if I run:

```
 $ sudo service mpd start
```

and check its status, I get

> systemd[1]: Started Music Player Daemon.

Note that in what is to come, assume that:

```
 $ sudo service mpd stop
```

has been run.

#### Questions

- What is the difference between the two, why does one give an error, and the other not?
- How can I track/find how the socket is being used? As mentioned, first we stop the service, if it is running?

  ```
  $ sudo service mpd stop
  ```

I search over stackexchange, and the solutions mentioned don't find anything.

```
$ sudo lsof -i -n -P|grep 6600
```

returns nothing

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 6600
```

return nothing

```
$ sudo ss -npt|grep 6600
```

return nothing. But, again,

```
$ mpd
```

returns

> socket: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use

What do I not understand?

Comment: Are you inside a vm à container or something like that ? Lsof is nicer When written : lsof -n -i TCP:6600 ;-)

Comment: If using systemd you should probably also try `sudo  systemctl stop mpd.socket` if it is using a socket to start the service.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Systemd

As [mentioned in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456909/socket-already-in-use-but-is-not-listed-mpd#comment830215_456909) you also need to stop the socket

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop mpd.socket
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but I had the same problem and setting bind_to_address in mpd.conf file to "0.0.0.0" seemed to fix it.

Also there is a good explanation of why that might be happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5106755/6321322)